# How can I select in Jquery a dynamically created set of div id

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

My problem is quite simple.
In my php page I generate as many divs as necessary through a "while" statement
Each div has got an ID which changes this way: `id='ref".$i"'` (Every time the While statement starts again to proceed, `$i` increases by 1, I mean `$i++`
Now I need to select all these divs in my JQUERY file

Comment: so many good ways to do that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **["starts with" ^=](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)** selector wildcard

```
$('[id^="ref"]')
// or
$('div[id^="ref"]') // if you want to be more specific
```

Once you have this Collection, if you want each value you can just loop through them with jQuery's `.each()`:

```
var valueArray = [];

$('div[id^="ref"]').each(function () {
    valueArray.push( $(this).text() ); // storing them all here
});

console.log( valueArray ); // all your values
```

Comment: OK, thanks. But if each div contains different values, how/where are they stored?

Comment: You can use `.each()` to loop through them and get the values, store them in an array... do whatever you want to do

Answer (score 0):

Give them all a class:

```
id='ref".$i"' class='mydivs'
```

and then select them by that class:

```
$("div.mydivs").doSomething()
```

Comment: OK, thanks. But if each div contains different values, how/where are they stored?

Comment: what kind of different values? different contents? then you would look at the contents..